# Is there a 'flowchart' or plan for Unity?

Tags: unity, source-code

I'm trying to understand a bit more about Unity.  I've downloaded the source-code, but from a starting point of no knowledge at all, I wonder if there is some kind of flowchart or plan that helps me to find my way around?  My specific need to know is because of a temporary problem I encountered while testing Wily.  I just did not know enough to try to find out about the problem, and re-installed the complete system.  If there's an easy way into the code, I haven't found it online as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the [official documentation of Unity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity).

On the home page, there is a link to [Unity Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Unity_Architecture.pdf). I hope it contains what you are looking for.